# como hacer un PG_DUMP desde un script, que me permita escoger que base de datos ignorar y cuales no

Tags: postgresql, bash

Estoy desarrollando un **Script** en el **Bash**, para la automatización de la creación de los **Backups** para el motor **Postgresql** en **Centos**, pero necesito tener la posibilidad de ignorar las bases de datos que defina en una variable.
y guardar el Dump en la carpeta raiz.

Aqui les muestro un ejemplo de mi Script, el cual me genera el Dump pero no se como ignorar algunas bases de datos y como decirle que haga todas las que yo quiera.

Muchas gracias, seria genial su ayuda

```
#!/bin/bash
usuario="postgres"
password="123"
db="test1"
puerto=5432 
host="localhost"
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
/usr/bin/pg_dump --host $host --port $puerto --username $usuario --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "/home/josealonso/Escritorio/backup2/B$db[$DATE].sql" "$db"
psql-l
```

Ajuntare el codigo que he logrado mejorar, durante el transcurso del dia:

```
#!/bin/bash
usuario='postgres'
password='123456a'
db=("test1" "test2")
puerto=5432 
host='localhost'
ignore=("test3")
for item in ${db[*]}
do
if [[ $item !=  $ignore ]];
then
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d
basedato=$item
/usr/bin/pg_dump --host $host --port $puerto --username $usuario --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "/home/josealonso/Escritorio/backup2/B$item[$DATE].sql" "$basedato"
echo 'El Backup De La Base de Datos' $basedato 'Fue Realizado con exito!!!'
sh script.sh
fi
done
```

Comment: "ignorar las bases de datos " o "ignorar las tablas de una base de datos" ? pg_dump solo backupea desde una base de datos.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, te explicare, mira tengo 3 bases de datos creadas y necesito hacerle el backup a solo 2 de ellas, entonces pg_dump debe generarme solo el backup de las 2 primeras y debe ignorar la 3, o las que defina en una variable ignore o algo asi.

Comment: Repito: `pg_dump` backupea *una* base de datos. Si quieres backupear dos, pues entonces ejecuta dos veces el script pasandole los nombres de tus dos bases de datos. Sinceramente, no entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: exacto el pg_dump genera una base de datos a la vez, es por esta razon que se necesite crear un ciclo **for**, lo siento, es ciero que mi pregunta esta un poco enredada, pero es debido a la complejidad la situacion problema que se me planteo, sin embargo creo que si puedes leer los comentarios y las respuestas a la pregunta podrias entenderme mucho mejor.

Comment: Para qué vas a hacer un `for` para _dos_ bases de datos ??

Comment: lo que pasa es que no son 2 bases de datos, en realidad son **n** bases de datos, pero estoy haciendo el trabajo inicial para 2, pues creo que es mas sencilllo comenzar con la menor informacion posible, tambien no entiendo su pregunta, pues usted me sugirio que realizara un archivo por cada **base de datos**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a proponerte una alternativa a lo que quieres. En mi opinión la solución más económica es hacer un archivo de respaldo (o *backup*) por cada base, ¿te interesa? Si quieres tener un solo archivo, al final del proceso se podría empaquetar. Usar un `for` en bash es *relativamente* trivial y podría solucionar tu problema.

```
#!/bin/bash
usuario="postgres"
password="123"
bases=(base1 base2)   # Esto es un arreglo con tus bases
puerto=5432 
host="localhost"
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
# Aqui inicia el ciclo que genera los respaldos
for db in "${bases[@]}"
do 
  echo "Creando el respaldo de ${db}"
  /usr/bin/pg_dump --host $host --port $puerto --username $usuario --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "/home/josealonso/Escritorio/backup2/B${db}[$DATE].sql" "${db}"
done
# Esto crea un archivo compactado con tus respaldos
tar cjf respaldo[$DATE].tar.bz2 /home/josealonso/Escritorio/backup2/
psql-l
```

Usando un arreglo con los nombres de las bases que quieres respaldar, hacemos un ciclo ``for` que genera un archivo por cada respaldo.

Al terminar, creamos un archivo compactado con el contenido del directorio. Pongo BZ2 por costumbre, pero puedes usar zip si así lo prefieres.

> #### Nota
>
> No he probado el script, pero espero que te sirva la idea.

Comment: Muchasimas gracias por tu idea, casualmente luego de escribir mi pregunta, habia pensado en realizar un ciclo **for** y y tambien guarde las bases de datos en archivos independientes, pero no habia pensado en crear un archivo **compactado** para todos los Backups, veo que sabes mucho del tema a mi me ha costado 2 semanas en resolverlo y veo que tu lo resolviste en menos de 1 dia. se me olvidaba decirte que necesitaba ignorar algunas, y esta fue la parte que mas me ha costado pues soy nuevo en **Bash**

Comment: @JOSELUISALONSOMERCADO modifica y prueba el script. Si te sirve, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada (hay un icono de check/paloma debajo del marcador de votos). Recuerda que puedes hacer todas las preguntas que necesites, solo asegúrate, si es posible, de incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: tienes razon, la proxima trataré de incluir mas información en mi postulación de mi pregunta, sin embargo para responder por comleto esta pregunta aun faltaba una parte crucial, y es la de hacer que el **pg_dump* ignore ciertas bases de datos a las cuales no necesite realizarles el **backup**, adjuntare el codigo que editado.

Comment: @JOSELUISALONSOMERCADO en la variable `bases` solo debes colocar aquellas que quieres descargar. Si tienes tres bases, digamos `base1`, `base2` y `base3` pero solo quieres el respaldo de `base1` y `base2`, solo coloca esas dos bases en la variable `bases`, como se ve en el ejemplo.

Comment: edite la pregunta para añadir el codigo que logre mejorar durante el transcurso del dia, es muy buena la sugerencia sin emabargo tenia que crear una variable ignore o algo asi pues asi me plantearon el ejercicio. tendre en cuenta todos sus aportes, espero poder temrinarlo hoy mismo.

Comment: tienen alguna sugerencia para la restauracion de los archivos creados??? con el **codigo** anterior...